# Paint many pins of various colors. iOS. Swift 3. Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift

I need to paint 100 pins on a map, up to 4 different colors in attention to a variable created by my 'colorOfPin' (green, yellow, red and blue).

Through a function, I loop to generate the 100 annotations of the 100 pines:

```
func paintPinsIP () {

    for item in 0 ... (numberPoints - 1) {

            let annotationPin = LocationPoint ()

            annotationPin.namePoint= elements [item].namePoint
            annotationPin.coordinate = elements [item].coordinate

            identificaPin = annotationPin.namePoint

            viewOfMap.addAnnotation(annotationPin)

              }
    }
```

Next I show those 100 annotations on the map, but each pin must have the color indicated by the variable ‘colorOfPin’ (green, yellow, red or blue):

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {return nil}

    let pinIdentifier = identificaPin

    var aView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: pinIdentifier)
    if aView == nil {
        let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pinIdentifier)
        guard annotation is LocationPoint else {return nil}

        pinView.isEnabled = true
        pinView.canShowCallout = false
        aView = pinView

        switch colorOfPin {
            case .red: pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
            case .yellow: pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.yellow
            case .green: pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.green
            case .blue: pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.blue
            }

    } else {
        aView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return aView
}
```

But the 100 points appear on the map with the color of the last pin. The color of all the points is the color of pin # 99. As the ‘colorOfPin’ variable of point # 99 is 'blue', the 100 pins appear blue.

How can I do to paint each pin of the color indicated by the variable ‘colorOfPin’?

Comment: Where is `colorOfPin` set to a value?

Comment: What happens when the dequeued annotation view is not nil? How is the colour set in that case?

Answer (score 0):

> As the ‘colorOfPin’ variable of point # 99 is 'blue', the 100 pins appear blue.

Set a breakpoint in your `paintPinsIP()` and `mapView(_:viewFor:)` methods and take a look at the order in which these methods are called. You're not setting the value of `colorOfPin` in `mapView(_:viewFor:)`, so it looks like you're expecting the map view to fetch the annotation view as soon as you add the annotation to the map. What really happens, though, is that you add a bunch of annotations to the map, and some time later, when the map tries to draw itself, it calls `mapView(_:viewFor:)` to get views for any annotations that happen to be visible. By that time, `colorOfPin` will have changed.

It looks like `LocationPoint` is probably a class you've created that adopts the `MKAnnotation` protocol. What you should do to fix your problem is to add a `pinColor` property to that class, so that you can set the color for the pin when you create the annotation. Then, when the map view calls your `mapView(_:viewFor:)` method for one of your annotations, you can use it's `pinColor` property to set the pin annotation view's `pinTintColor` property.